# Rust製ゲームエンジンPistonのバックエンドは何？

Tags: rust

Rust製ゲームエンジンPistonのバックエンド（DirectX、OpenGL）はなんですか？

Answer (score 1):

[Piston overview, Backends](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/piston/wiki/Piston-overview#backends) より：

> These integrates Piston with various external APIs. The window and graphics backends are decoupled. The reason is greater flexibility when shipping a product, easier to compare API design and performance, and works both for cross and native platforms.
>
> Window (uses the piston core):
>
> - pistoncore-glfw_window
> - pistoncore-glutin_window
> - pistoncore-sdl2_window
>
> 2D graphics (uses piston2d-graphics:
>
> - piston2d-opengl_graphics
> - piston2d-gfx_graphics
> - piston2d-glium_graphics